# Error installing Jupyter & pywinpty (Python)

Tags: python, jupyter

I'm trying to install Jupyter on **Python 3.7** and seem to be stumbling over this error again and again;

```
winpty/cywinpty.c(598): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'winpty.h': No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.14.26428\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

I get the same error when attempting to install pywinpty via pip.

I have installed & reinstalled the build tools to no avail and the command window   is elevated - any ideas?

UPDATE: Not quite resolved in 3.7 - but **it worked fine in 3.6**, I've rolled back.

Comment: Same for me issues on 3.8 rolled back to 3.6 for fix

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Temporarily, until standard way does not work for Python 3.7, you can install `pywinpty` manually by using the prebuilt wheel from [Gohlke's collection](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pywinpty) and then install `jupyter` with `pip`.

To install manually (from *cmd* or *Powershell*) use:

`pip install drive:\path\to\the\wheel\pywinpty-0.5.4-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl`

Comment: Annoying that this product is used so widely among everyone, including windows users. And in 2020 this is still an issue that most beginners following guides and recommendations will bump in to and most likely struggle with.

Comment: There's an easier way to install from Gohlke's collection, which is to use `pipwin`. Install `pipwin` using `pip install pipwin` and then use it in place of `pip` whenever something doesn't work.

Comment: Dear @ParamSiddharth it was a good substitute answer

Comment: I hit this issue with trying to install Jupyterlab and the only way around it was manually installing the prebuilt wheel. Thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: the problem persisted until 2022 and this is still the valid solution in 2022

Answer (score 5):

I've a concrete solution for you guys... I'm also facing the same issue like you guys as it arises with **python3.7 or later versions**... But don't worry

***I currently have Python 3.9.2***

[image: ERROR : image]

**Follow these Steps:-**

**--> Write these Commands in the cmd**

1. Just install pywinpty by using [Gholke s Collection](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pywinpty)
2. Now, just download it [image: Pywinpty link]
3. Now, copy the path of the file, from where you have downloaded it... In my case it is [image: file address]
4. After successfully installed Pywinpty... now **"pip install jupyter"**
5. Then it's DONE... Now launch the notebook using **"jupyter notebook"**

In case its not been done... Make a comment below...

Answer (score 4):

There's an easier way to install from Gohlke's collection, which is to use `pipwin`. Install `pipwin` using `pip install pipwin` and then use it in place of `pip` whenever something doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I will leave this option here too. You can install the pywinpty 0.5.7 induvidually and then the rest of the installation can continue.

```
python -m pip install pywinpty==0.5.7
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe your Python version is too high (e.g. 3.12.x), the Pywinpty doesn't support this version, try to install python 3.10.x. It works for me.

Comment: OP clearly states that they are using Python 3.7.