# errors when installing jupyter notebook on Windows 10

Tags: python, sdk, jupyter-notebook

I run `pip install jupyter` in command prompt, but I get the following error

```
building 'winpty.cywinpty' extension
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with ...(a URL)
```

So I install the Visual Studio Build Tools 2017 15.8.1 with the default options selected, including the Windows 10 SDK (10.0.17134.0), but then when I run `pip install jupyter` I get another error:

```
cywinpty.c
winpty/cywinpty.c(598): fetal error C1083: Cannot include file: 'winpty.h': No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.15.26726\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Command "c:\python37\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\cyh\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ffl96cvn\\pywinpty\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\cyh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-1psgkfzm\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\cyh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ffl96cvn\pywinpty\
```

What are those errors and what should I do?

Thanks

Comment: This question has previously been addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51260909/error-installing-jupyter-pywinpty-python).