# Jupyter Notebook: Terminals not available

Tags: python-3.x, terminal, jupyter

Yesterday I had problems launching Jupyter Notebook (all of sudden I got the notification, that python was not working properly, but before everything was working well...). So I decided to upgrade to the latest python version. And now I can launch jupyter notebook, however I get this error message:

> Terminals not available (error was No module named 'winpty.cywinpty')

I followed the setps descriebd [here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51260909/error-installing-jupyter-pywinpty-python)

But still get this error message. Is there a way, to solve this? Or does anyone have an advise?

EDIT: This is what I get when I run jupyter notebook from the cmd:

```
[W 14:17:04.451 NotebookApp] Terminals not available (error was No module named 'winpty.cywinpty')
[I 14:17:05.073 NotebookApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from C:\Users\Fati\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab
[I 14:17:05.073 NotebookApp] JupyterLab application directory is C:\Users\Fati\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\share\jupyter\lab
[I 14:17:05.323 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: C:\Users\Fati
[I 14:17:05.324 NotebookApp] Jupyter Notebook 6.1.5 is running at:
[I 14:17:05.326 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=8e859b3108946a8310e1e5ceed6d2186c8731261fc5161eb
[I 14:17:05.330 NotebookApp]  or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=8e859b3108946a8310e1e5ceed6d2186c8731261fc5161eb
[I 14:17:05.331 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 14:17:05.448 NotebookApp]
```

Comment: please provide a full-error message. BTW in the question u mentioned, `UPDATE: Not quite resolved in 3.7 - but it worked fine in 3.6, I've rolled back.` So try python 3.6?

Comment: I published the error message in my question (Edit). A couple of days ago, I was using 3.7 and everything worked until 2 days ago. So I'm not sure, if I should change or if there might be other solutions?

Answer (score 16):

I had the same problem using Python 3.9 and resolved it by installing wheel and pywinpty using pipwin:

`pip install pipwin`

`pip uninstall wheel`

`pipwin install wheel`

`pip uninstall pywinpty`

`pipwin install pywinpty`

After restarting Jupyter the error is gone.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by [Scott Roberts' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65552261/4659442), using Python 3.9 I resolved the issue by updating pywinpty from version 0.5.7 to version 1.1.3:

`pip install --upgrade pywinpty`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I just resolved by re-installing Jupyter notebook in Conda

```
conda install jupyter notebooks
```